# Python парсинг данных веб страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

недавно решил написать парсер по урокам в ютубе.
В общем хотел написать парсер что будет выдавать название всех бесплатных на данный момент игр.
Только вот он выдавал только пустую строчку, я уже пытался переписать код, и смотрел может у кого-то есть такая же проблема - но ничего не нашел.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://steamdb.info/upcoming/free'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(req.content, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"app"})
for x in name:
    title = x.find("td > a > b")
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты посмотри какой ответ у тебя вылезает: `<Response [403]>` - доступ запрещен, а если посмотреть в текст, там написано, что надо пройти капчу (просто запиши `req.text` в какой-нибудь файл `html` и открой в браузере).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы выполните следующий код, то увидите получаемую в запросе страницу. Она не содержит данных, которые вы хотите получить. По причине динамического наполнения страницы JavaScript или какой-нибудь защиты.

```
import requests

url = 'https://steamdb.info/upcoming/free'
req = requests.get(url)

with open('file.html', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(req.text)
```

Либо выберите другой сайт для изучения парса (без динамического наполнения), либо посмотрите в сторону, например, `selenium` чтоб на страницах отрабатывал JavaScript.

Comment: @0andriy вопрос не связан с гугл. Запрос отправляется на `steamdb.info`

Comment: Ах, это имелись в виду видеоуроки...

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться selenium и быстро открыть браузер, сохранить страницу и закрыть его, а потом работать со страницей. Для работы надо:

```
pip install selenium 
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Пример кода:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://steamdb.info/upcoming/free/"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
browser.close()
content = soup.select('tr.app.sub > td > a > b')
for item in content:
  print(item.text)
```

Вывод:

```
Tennis World Tour - DLC 11 - Garcia
Tennis World Tour - DLC 14 - Shapovalov
Tennis World Tour - DLC 13 - De Minaur
Tennis World Tour - DLC 14 - Shapovalov
Tennis World Tour - DLC 11 - Garcia
Geneshift
Kao the Kangaroo: Round 2
Killing Floor 2
Kingdom Come: Deliverance
Tropico 6
Warhammer 40,000: Mechanicus
Project Highrise
```